# How can I count the duplicate items present in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to get the frequency of each item of every list in a list.

For example, given:

```
my_list = [['Wheels', 'Handle', 'Service'], 
          ['Wheels', 'Forks', 'Handle', 'Wheels', 'Service'],
          ['Motor Sensor', 'Motor Sensor', 'Electronic']]
```

I want to output the following:

```
[{'Wheels':1,'Handle':1,'Service':1},
 {'Wheels':2, 'Forks':1,'Handle':1,'Service':1},
 {'Motor Sensor':2,'Electronic':1}]
```

Comment: `list(map(Counter, my_list))`, `Counter` is `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter()` on each sublist, and then transform them to dictionaries.

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = [['Wheels', 'Handle', 'Service'], 
           ['Wheels', 'Forks', 'Handle', 'Wheels', 'Service'],
           ['Motor Sensor', 'Motor Sensor', 'Electronic']]
           
result = [dict(Counter(sublist)) for sublist in my_list]
print(result)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `set`s, as they only enumerate distinct items, thus using the difference of item count to measure the occurrence of each item ..... but your solution is way slicker and shorter.

+1